# UIButton highlight state images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I've a `UIButton` and I set it with:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

UIImage *imageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"];
UIImage *imageNormalHover = [UIImage imageNamed:@"normalHover.png"];
UIImage *imageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
UIImage *imageSelectedHover = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedHover.png"];

[myButton setImage:imageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:imageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

if (boolVar) {
    [myButton setSelected:YES];
    [myButton setImage:imageSelectedHover forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
} else {
    [myButton setImage:imageNormalHover forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

The issue is when the state is normal and I try to press the button I see correctly the image `normalHover.png` but when the state is selected and I try to press the button I see still `normalHover.png` and not the `selectedHover.png`. It seems that with `UIButton` I'm unable to change the highlighted image. Do you how to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the image for the `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted` combined state:

```
[myButton setImage:imageSelectedHover forState:(UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted)];
```

Because both states are on when the button is selected and you hignlight it by tapping on it.

Answer (score 0):

In swift this is done with `union`:

```
myButton.setImage(imageSelectedHover, forState: UIControlState.Selected.union(UIControlState.Highlighted))
```